# How to create array indide an array in JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have 3 form fields. I want to make a JSON array. I don't know how to make my requirement like JSON array, inside one filled only I want to make one more array. I am trying, but I am not able to create.

```js
var title = $("#title").val();
var authorities = $(".your_profile option:selected").val();
var edition = $("#edition").val();
response = [];
var activated = true;
authorities=[];
var authorities = $(".your_profile option:selected").val();
var createdDate= "2016-12-13T13:35:24.451Z";   
   response.push({activated:activated,authorities:authorities,createdDate:createdDate});
   console.log(response);
```

```html
Title:<input type="text" id="title">
authorities:<selected>
 <option value="Agent">Agent</option>
 <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
 <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
</selected>
Title:<input type="text" id="edition">
<input type="button" id="btn-submit" value="submit">
```

I need output like this

```
[
    {
        "title": "Professional JavaScript",
        "authorities": [
            "Nicholas C. Zakas"
        ],
        "edition": "3",
    },
]
```

Comment: You're overriding the `authorities` value with single input value. You need to push this value into the array: `var authorities=[]; authorities.push($(".your_profile option:selected").val());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

> Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert your data to json

```js
$(function() {

    $("#submitBtn").click(function(e){
      //Prevent the default behaviour
      e.preventDefault();
      var title =$("#title").val();
      var authorities = $("#selection").val();
      var edition =$("#edition").val();
      var response = new Object();
      response.title = title;
      response.authorities = [authorities];
      response.edition = edition;
      var json_str = JSON.stringify(response);
      console.log(json_str);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>Title:
<br>
<input type="text" id="title">
<br>
Authorities:
<br>
<select id="selection">
    <option value="Agent">Agent</option>
    <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
    <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
</select>
<br>
Edition:
<br>
<input type="text" id="edition">
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="submit">
```

and to pass the data via ajax, you could do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'url_to_web_server',
   type: 'POST',
   data: json_str, // Your json variable here
   type: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
      // Handle success response here
   },
   error: function() {
      // Handle error response here
   }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If i removed the miltible means not working properly

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get you!

Comment: Insteed of this <select id="selection" multiple="multiple">, only i put like this means  not working <select id="selection">

Comment: If you remove `multiple` from `select`, then you'll get a single element on selection. And by the way its working too!

Comment: but output i need array formaat for that field how can do

Comment: @KaniR - I've updated my answer, please have a look. Just wrap your `authorities` variable with array brackets, and this would work like a charm :D

Comment: @KaniR - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: Ya nice, i have one more doubt please clear me ,how to pass the respose to another page through AJAX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130534/discussion-between-saumya-rastogi-and-kani-r).

Answer (score 0):

You may do in this way:

**HTML**

```
Title:<input type="text" id="title">
authorities:<select id="selection" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Agent">Agent</option>
    <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
    <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
</select>
Edition:<input type="text" id="edition">
<input type="button" id="btn-submit" value="submit">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#btn-submit").click(function(evt){
    //Prevent the default behaviour
    evt.preventDefault();
    var title =$("#title").val();
        var authorities = $("#selection").val();
        var edition =$("#edition").val();
    var response = new Object();
    response.title = title;
    response.authorities = authorities;
    response.edition = edition;
    var stringed = JSON.stringify(response);
    alert(stringed);
  });
});
```

If you try this code it will generate the string "**stringed**" as you wish

I hope this is useful

Angelo